# interfere WhateverCode generation but instead pass literally Whatever to custom infix operator

Tags: raku

```
# use Something;

sub infix:<-_->(*@args) is assoc("list") { @args.raku }

say * -_- 5
```

with this i get

```
WhateverCode.new
```

i expect

```
[Whatever, 5]
```

so it will pass Whatever object and not do closure generation

Answer (score 5):

`*` has a special grammatical meaning in that context.  There is (currently) no way around that.

If you want `[Whatever, 5]` to be the result in `@args`, you will need to write:

```
Whatever -_- 5
```

I guess it would be possible to have a pragma disabling whatevercode currying in the future, but a use-case has not presented itself yet.

Comment: thanks. you say grammatical meaning i see people doing slangs,  will it be possible to write slang to make this work? i dont know how to write it of course

Comment: @freddy [Relevant comment and code in compiler](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/a992d305725baa7113d7184563b4cc3396ff5934/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L10593-L10629). Comment starts with: "checks if we have something of the form `*` op *` [etc] and if so, and if it's not one of the ops we do not auto-curry for, emits a closure instead. We hard-code the things not to curry for now; in the future, we will inspect the ... the op to decide ...". So plan is one day there'll be 4 options per op: no curry, `Whatever` curry, `WhateverCode` curry, or both `Whatever` and `WhateverCode` curry (default).

Comment: @freddy Maybe you could create a slang module with a cut/paste of [the entire actions class](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/a992d305725baa7113d7184563b4cc3396ff5934/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L10593-L10629), with the op list in the code I just linked changed to include your op, and then use the slang mechanism to mix in your new version. But I'm not 100% sure that would work, and I *am* sure it would mean you're either batshit crazy or will end up that way. 

Comment: @freddy @raiph  Please don't do any work on the `src/Perl6` directory anymore.  It will be obsolete when 6.e lands.  Any work on slangs should probably focus on the grammar and actions in `src/Raku`, and use the [Slangify](https://raku.land/zef:lizmat/Slangify) module now.